# yeoman ignore option in this.fs.copy() does not ignore files

Tags: yeoman

I try to create a template for a C# project with Yeoman. When I copy files from templates folder to destination folder, I would like to ignore setting files. Here is what I am doing but does not work

```
this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath(),
      this.destinationPath(), {
        globOptions: {
          ignore: ["appsettings.Development.template.json"]
        }
      }
    )
```

I tried to replace `"appsettings.Development.template.json"` with `*.template.*`, `appsettings.*.template.*` and `*.*.template.*`. Everytime when I run `yo`, `appsettings.Development.template.json` file is always copied.

Can I please get some help? Thank you.

The full version of the `index.js` is as follow:

```
var Generator = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = class extends Generator {

  constructor(args, opts) {
    super(args, opts);
  }

  async prompting() {
    this.answers = await this.prompt([{
        type: "input",
        name: "projectName",
        message: "Your project name (separate all lowercase words by -, kebabCase)",
      },
      {
        type: "input",
        name: "databaseName",
        message: "Your database name (PascalCase)",
      }
    ]);

    this.answers.pascalProjectName = this.kebabCaseToPascalCase(this.answers.projectName);
    this.log(this.answers.databaseName);
  }

  writing() {
    this.fs.copy(
      this.templatePath(),
      this.destinationPath(), {
        globOptions: {
          ignore: ["appsettings.Development.template.json"]
        }
      }
    );
  }

  kebabCaseToPascalCase = (kebabCase) => {
    this.log(kebabCase);
    let words = kebabCase.split('-');
    this.log(words);
    return words.map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)).join('');
  }
}
```